# What's that ship in the opening credits of 'Star Trek: Enterprise'?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, star-trek-enterprise

In the Star Trek: Enterprise opening credits it seems to step through starship history up to the Enterprise NX-01.

After Cochran's Phoenix, there is a ship that we see almost *only* from behind, and then the Enterprise. **Do we know what that ship is?**

[image]

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is the [S.S. Emmette](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/SS_Emmette), designed by [Doug Drexler](http://web.archive.org/web/20120716181324/http://drexfiles.wordpress.com/2009/04/25/eureka-iss-emette/).

> *This time for real! Here it is, one of the most mysterious of all the
> Enterprise ships, the S.S Emmette. Teasingly seen in the notorious
> title sequence over what appears to be a moon base.*
>
> *Look at the massive rocket style motors on the back of this bucket!
> These giants suggest that perhaps this ship was meant primarily for
> solar exploration and testing. The reasoning being  that you would not
> devote so much of the ship’s resources to engines like these unless
> they could made a difference.  Set up like this, if you lost warp
> drive within the solar system, you were still capable of making it
> home.*
>
> *Fascinating similarities to the Romulan Bird of Prey, suggesting some
> truth to the theory that the Romulan’s had stolen intel on this ship,
> and built their own version.*
>
> *When the gang at Foundation Imaging were working on the title
> sequence, clearly they only built as much of the Emmette as they
> needed. Note the absence of detail on the front of the model.*
>
> <sub><sup>[eureka! s.s. emmette!](http://web.archive.org/web/20130126235526/http://drexfiles.wordpress.com/2009/04/25/eureka-iss-emette/)</sup></sub>

[image]

[image]